# Pegar dados do botão em jQuery e chamar Modal

Tags: jquery

Tenho o seguinte botão:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-custom" name="deletar" id="<? echo $valor->set_cod; ?>"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></button>
```

Preciso pegar o id="", e depois de buscar o id, gostaria de chamar a modal do bootstrap mesmo, com a mensagem para exclusão, que por sua vez, faz a ação quando for pressionado o botão OK. Como faço?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode usar os atributos **data-href** com a url para deletar o registro. Ex: data-href="deletar.php?id=set_cod; ?>"

Com jquery o seguinte codigo, garante a ação ao confirmar

```
$('#nome-sua-modal').on('show.bs.modal', function(e) {
  //btn-ok é a classe do botão confirmar na modal
  $(this).find('.btn-ok').attr('href',        $(e.relatedTarget).data('href'));
});
```

Aqui tem um exemplo completo:   [exemplo](http://plnkr.co/edit/rVltLIIy7nMy0rhslJup?p=preview%20Exemplo)

Comment: Perfeita resposta, isso mesmo. Obrigado!

Answer (score 1):

Para abrir um modal no bootstrap você usa o `data-target`:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" 
    data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">

 <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" 
    tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
 </div>
```

Se precisar realizar alguma coisa no evento click do botão você pode usar o  `onclick=minhaFuncao(id)` passando o id para a função.

```
function minhaFuncao(id) {
    // fazer algo aqui
}
```

Caso o id do modal for obtido via php, pode usar a mesma forma de passar o id para ambos os casos (data-target do botão e id do modal).